# Should I keep back straight in jefferson squat?

Tags: deadlifts

Some videos showing people bending their back to pick up bar at very bottom [eg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_jFnh_Vs6E). I feel this is quite natural to me too but some instructional videos, eg by Ryan Humiston say that one should keep straight back at all times [see here](https://youtu.be/VzQhgHPoi4s?si=vU1Sr27v50gV7V-y&t=58).

Could someone advice?

Comment: Keeping a straight back is just safe practice for near enough all exercises, upper and lower.

Comment: You are linking to Jefferson Squats. There are also Jefferson Curls, which are closer to deadlifts and *certainly* are done from a flexed back since that's the whole point of the exercise. Please keep your terminology straight.

Answer (score 2):

You should strive to have a neutral (straight) back for a Jefferson deadlift/squat or other deadlift variation unless that variation is designed to train under a flexed back. Particularly the lower back.

You can even see in Eric's video that his back is *mostly* straight. He is actively trying to keep it straight as he can under that load. If he was not doing that, then his entire back would be far more curved.

You should also not take technique queues from highly advanced trained athletes training at near maximal loads. Eric Bugenhagen is a professional wrestler who has been lifting really heavy weights for decades. His body is adapted at handling heavy loads in various conditions, so he's capable of getting away with excessive form breakdown from time to time.

And anybody, no matter how strong they are, is going to have form breakdown at a near maximal or maximal load. However they strive to keep form throughout the lift which allows them to power through it.

Comment: My question is , how do you pick the bar without bending over at all?

Comment: @ReineAbstraktion Part of it is you just need to keep practicing. Your back and abs will get stronger and be able to better brace your spine.  Brace your abs and lats, then lift with your legs.

Comment: @trystwithfreedom You *will* bend/flex your back. That's not a bad thing in and of itself, nor can it be completely avoided. It should not happen without bracing and with weights that cause pain, though.